# Starting a JAR/Java file over Custom URI Scheme

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, batch-file, registry

I have managed to create a Batch file which can be executed using
`<a href="testbatch: -username admin -password pass123 OpenForm?id=111">Open Batch file</a>`

Here I am just testing handling switches the important part is `testBatch:` I have the registry set up correctly for the batch file as it runs. I can also call the jar file from within the batch file with no problems, unless its in the new edge browser, then I get a jar file not found(no Idea why).

So I modify the registry and link it to the jar file to be executed. The reg file looks like.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava]
@="URL: test Java"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava\shell\open\command]
@="\"java.exe\" -jar \"C:\\Users\\Public\\testApp.jar\" %1"
```

When I make the URI call of `testJava:` I get the usual prompt to run the jar file on the local machine which suggests it is accessing it fine. Then I allow it and the command prompt flashes very quickly but doesn't run the jar.

All the Jar file does is create a .txt file. and it have tested it works via clicking it/ running it in cmd and it works in batch.

What should I do to run the jar file?

**EDIT UPDATE:**
I have managed to get it to launch from edge and internet explorer directly to the jar file I wanted. I had to explicitly locate the java.exe before starting my jar file. so my Reg file now looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava]
@="URL: testJava"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testJava\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_51\\bin\\java.exe\" -jar \"C:\\Users\\Public\\testApp.jar\" %1"
```

Still not sure why this is? and also it is unknown why running a batch file from edge that launches the jar file also doesn't work.

**EDIT UPDATE 2**

I have made the batch file locate the java.exe explicitly and it now works in Edge browser. Weird?

Comment: Is `java.exe` in PATH? Check it by running `java` from the Command prompt from an arbitrary folder e.g. `cd /d c:\ & java`

Comment: yea it gives me the java usage text